# Не отвечает порт 3000 Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Q, я работаю на версии RoR 5.2.3 и на Ruby 2.3.7, юзаю Nginx+Passenger. Хотел создать своё первое веб-приложение, но после апгрейда RoR с 4.2.0 версии на пятую у меня вдруг резко перестал отвечать порт 3000. То есть я, как всегда, захожу в окно терминала, вписываю `cd blog`, получаю ответ, а затем пишу `rails server`. В итоге получается как-то так:

```
iMac-Kali:blog andrw$ rails server
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.3 application starting in development 
=> Run 'rails server -h' for more startup options
A server is already running. Check /Users/andrw/blog/tmp/pids/server.pid.
Exiting
```

После всех этих процедур у меня не получается зайти по адресу [localhost:3000](http://localhost:3000). То есть у меня идёт вечная загрузка. Если к сведению, то у меня прекрасно получалось перейти на [localhost:3000](http://localhost:3000) до апгрейда RoR. Облазал весь гугл, ничего не могу поделать с такой ошибкой... Пожалуйста, помогите

Comment: `A server is already running` говорит о том, что сервер уже запущен, но что-то пошло не так. Вам нужно найти процесс (способ зависит от вашей ОС) и убить его. Ну или просто перезагрузить комп

Comment: Перезагрузил комп- моментально всё заработало, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На будущее, чтобы не перезапускать систему, Вы можете выполнить команду `lsof -i :3000`

*lsof - показывает все процессы связанные с файловыми дескрипторами*

*Флаг -i позволяет фильтровать сетевые сокеты*

Так Вы узнаете PID процесса, который используется.

Затем, выполните `sudo kill -9 YOURPID`

Вместо *YOURPID* укажите номер процесса.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте выполнить `killall rails`